# Grafana openldap auth：ldap users cannot be found by grafana

Tags: authentication, ldap, grafana

I've spent many days trying to get Grafana to authenticate users via LDAPS to Active Directory. If anyone has the required magic to get it to work, I'd be quite happy.

I'm having issues with Grafana. I figured this might be a good place to ask. I'm trying to use LDAPS auth for user authentication and failing at it.

env: ubuntu14.04   grafana6.2 openldap2.4.31

Here's the relevant part of my configuration file :

----------------ldap.toml----------

```
[[servers]]

host = "xx.xxx.xx.xxx"

port = 389

use_ssl = false

start_tls = false

ssl_skip_verify = false

bind_dn = "cn=admin,dc=sscc,dc=com"

bind_password = '123456'

search_filter = "(cn=%s)"

search_base_dns = ["dc=sscc,dc=com"]

group_search_filter = "(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid=%s))"

group_search_base_dns = ["cn=users,dc=sscc,dc=com"]

group_search_filter_user_attribute = "cn"

[servers.attributes]

name = "givenName"

surname = "sn"

username = "cn"

member_of = "dn"

email =  "email"

[[servers.group_mappings]]

group_dn = "cn=admin,dc=sscc,dc=com"

org_role = "Admin"

[[servers.group_mappings]]

group_dn = "cn=users,dc=sscc,dc=com"

org_role = "Editor"

org_id = 2
```

---

--------------default.ini---------

```
[auth.ldap]
enabled = true
config_file = /etc/grafana/ldap.toml
allow_sign_up = true

# LDAP backround sync (Enterprise only)
sync_cron = @hourly
active_sync_enabled = false
```

---

### Here is the ldap users info:

#### ldapsearch -LLL -w 123456 -x -H ldap://127.0.0.1 -D "cn=admin,dc=sscc,dc=com" -b

```
"cn=users,dc=sscc,dc=com"
dn: cn=users,dc=sscc,dc=com
gidNumber: 500
cn: users
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top

dn: cn=test1,cn=users,dc=sscc,dc=com
cn:: IHRlc3Qx
gidNumber: 500
homeDirectory: /home/users/test1
sn: test1
loginShell: /bin/sh
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
userPassword:: MTIzNDU2
uidNumber: 1000
uid: test1
mail: test1@sscc.com
```

---

When i log in using "test1", it will failed.

### Here is failed log:

```
t=2019-11-21T21:16:25-0500 lvl=info msg="Searching for user's groups" logger=ldap filter="(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid= test1))"
t=2019-11-21T21:16:25-0500 lvl=info msg="Second bind failed" logger=ldap error="LDAP Result Code 49 \"Invalid Credentials\": "
t=2019-11-21T21:16:25-0500 lvl=eror msg="Error while trying to authenticate user" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= error="Invalid Username or Password"
t=2019-11-21T21:16:25-0500 lvl=eror msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=POST path=/login status=500 remote_addr=xx.xxx.xx.x time_ms=9 size=53 referer=http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:3000/login
```

---

### But  when i set group_mappings:

```
[[servers.group_mappings]]
# If you want to match all (or no ldap groups) then you can use wildcard
group_dn = "*"
org_role = "Viewer"
org_id = 3
```

---

I can succeed by using "test1".I don't know why.
I think there may be some incorrect parameter settings.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `test1` user is not a member of the `users` group.

Membership of a [PosixGroup](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/PosixGroup) is defined by one or more `memberUid` attributes that point to a user's `uid`.
Your first log message shows the query filter used to search for groups containing a member with Uid `test1`: `(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid= test1))`

The `users` group contains an attribute `objectClass=posixGroup`, but it does not contain an attribute `memberUid=test1`, so it is not returned by the query. In order for `test1` to access the Editor role, the `users` group should have a corresponding `memberUid` attribute defining them as a member:

```
dn: cn=users,dc=sscc,dc=com
gidNumber: 500
cn: users
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
memberUid: test1
```

---

Whenever you define a group mapping with `group_dn="*"`, then any authenticated user with a valid `uid` will be authorized for that role regardless of group membership. This is why `test1` was able to access the Viewer role once it was configured to ignore group membership.